# How to use entire disk space in Windows 10 when installing from system image?

Tags: windows, windows-10, partitioning, installation

I created a system image of my Windows installation.

My original hard drive size was 120gb.

When I installed from the system image onto a 500gb hard drive I had unallocated space. The problem is I cannot extend the 120gb volume into this unallocated space because the recovery partition is in between the 120gb space and the unallocated space.

I did a quick web search and supposedly there is software that will allow extending into the unallocated space. But I'd rather restore from the image again if there is a way to use the entire drive during installation.

Is there a way to do this during installation using system image?

Comment: Few questions that would help people who would answer.
1. Where did you store the image? On same disk or another (normally it would not allow the same disk)?
2. Is this image is one that can be used to perform a bare metal recovery?
3. On System Image backup dialog, you should see 'Format and Repartition' option. Did you see it or not? This can be used to clean and load.

Comment: Yes, you could use diskpart too using the command console or even by pressing shift+F10 in a Windows preboot environment. Good to hear you have resolved the problem.

Comment: Please don't edit the answer into your question. [su] is a question and answer site and answers should be separate from questions. You can [answer your own question](http://superuser.com/help/self-answer) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Diskpart to delete the recovery partitions which allowed me to extend the partition into the unallocated spaces.